# LIMIT per group - Google BigQuery/Standard SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table like the following (example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c9acb1/3/0)):

```
CREATE TABLE topics (
  name varchar(64),
  url varchar(253),
  statistic integer,
  pubdate timestamp
);

INSERT INTO topics VALUES
('a',  'b',  100,  TIMESTAMP '2011-05-16 15:36:38'),  
('a',  'c',  110,  TIMESTAMP '2014-04-01 00:00:00'),  
('a',  'd',  120,  TIMESTAMP '2014-04-01 00:00:00'),  
('a',  'e',  90,   TIMESTAMP '2011-05-16 15:36:38'), 
('a',  'f',  80,   TIMESTAMP '2014-04-01 00:00:00'), 
('a',  'g',  70,   TIMESTAMP '2011-05-16 15:36:38'), 
('a',  'h',  150,  TIMESTAMP '2014-04-01 00:00:00'),  
('a',  'i',  50,   TIMESTAMP '2011-05-16 15:36:38'), 
('b',  'j',  10,   TIMESTAMP '2014-04-01 00:00:00'), 
('b',  'k',  11,   TIMESTAMP '2011-05-16 15:36:38'), 
('b',  'l',  12,   TIMESTAMP '2014-04-01 00:00:00'), 
('b',  'm',  9,    TIMESTAMP '2011-05-16 15:36:38'),
('b',  'n',  8,    TIMESTAMP '2014-04-01 00:00:00'),
('b',  'o',  7,    TIMESTAMP '2011-05-16 15:36:38'),
('b',  'p',  15,   TIMESTAMP '2014-04-01 00:00:00'), 
('b',  'q',  5,    TIMESTAMP '2011-05-16 15:36:38'),
('b',  'r',  2,    TIMESTAMP '2014-04-01 00:00:00')
```

I would like to take the top two rows based on their `statistic` value _from each (`name, date(pubdate)`) combination.

In other words, I would like to `GROUP BY name, date(pubdate)`, but without an aggregate function, and instead with the result simply taking the top two rows based on their `statistic` from each group.  (So, I know it is not really a `GROUP BY`, but rather a `greatest-n-per-group`.)

I'm using Google Big Query with Standard SQL.  I've looked at a number of other [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2129693/7954504) but am unsure how to achieve the result in this case.

Desired result:

```
name    url     statistic   date

a       b       100         2011-05-16
a       e       90          2011-05-16

a       h       150         2014-04-01
a       d       120         2014-04-01

b       m       9           2011-05-16
b       k       11          2011-05-16

b       l       12          2014-04-01
b       p       15          2014-04-01
```

Comment: Do you have a column with a primary key also as that is needed to get a pure deterministic (fixed) result always as the results can still be non deterministic  (random) without even when using `ORDER BY statistic` as the statistic column values are not unique

Comment: You mean that in the case of "ties" for `statistic` the result would not be guaranteed to be deterministic?  @RaymondNijland

Comment: *"You mean that in the case of "ties" for statistic the result would not be guaranteed to be deterministic? "* yes indeed that is what i mean @BradSolomon ideally you should use `ORDER BY some_column, <some_columns_with_primary_key>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(arr) FROM (
  SELECT name, DATE(pubdate) day, 
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(url, statistic) ORDER BY statistic DESC LIMIT 2) arr
  FROM `project.dataset.table`   
  GROUP BY name, day
), UNNEST(arr)
-- ORDER BY name, day
```

You can test, play with above using sample data in your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'a' name, 'b' url,  100 statistic,  TIMESTAMP '2011-05-16 15:36:38' pubdate UNION ALL  
  SELECT 'a', 'c',  110,  '2014-04-01 00:00:00' UNION ALL  
  SELECT 'a', 'd',  120,  '2014-04-01 00:00:00' UNION ALL  
  SELECT 'a', 'e',  90,   '2011-05-16 15:36:38' UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'a', 'f',  80,   '2014-04-01 00:00:00' UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'a', 'g',  70,   '2011-05-16 15:36:38' UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'a', 'h',  150,  '2014-04-01 00:00:00' UNION ALL  
  SELECT 'a', 'i',  50,   '2011-05-16 15:36:38' UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'b', 'j',  10,   '2014-04-01 00:00:00' UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'b', 'k',  11,   '2011-05-16 15:36:38' UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'b', 'l',  12,   '2014-04-01 00:00:00' UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'b', 'm',  9,    '2011-05-16 15:36:38' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', 'n',  8,    '2014-04-01 00:00:00' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', 'o',  7,    '2011-05-16 15:36:38' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', 'p',  15,   '2014-04-01 00:00:00' UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'b', 'q',  5,    '2011-05-16 15:36:38' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', 'r',  2,    '2014-04-01 00:00:00' 
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(arr) FROM (
  SELECT name, DATE(pubdate) day, 
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(url, statistic) ORDER BY statistic DESC LIMIT 2) arr
  FROM `project.dataset.table`  
  GROUP BY name, day
), UNNEST(arr)
ORDER BY name, day
```

with result

```
Row name    day         url statistic    
1   a       2011-05-16  b   100  
2   a       2011-05-16  e   90   
3   a       2014-04-01  h   150  
4   a       2014-04-01  d   120  
5   b       2011-05-16  k   11   
6   b       2011-05-16  m   9    
7   b       2014-04-01  p   15   
8   b       2014-04-01  l   12
```

Comment: Nice, this looks to be precisely what I was after.

Comment: @BradSolomon - glad it helped! consider voting up then :o) if not yet

Comment: @BradSolomon mind mine comment about deterministic results as this will not guarantee pure deterministic (fixed) results always as `statistic ` column is not unique... Not sure how important it is for your user case.

Comment: Thanks @RaymondNijland, though in this case I am willing to accept non-determinism in the case of the very-rare tie

Comment: One more question for you here @MikhailBerlyant - any way to display the original `pubdate` timestamp in the result rather than its `date()`?

Comment: Nevermind, got it - that would just include `pubdate` in the `STRUCT` call and exclude it from the top `select`

Answer (score 4):

Use the `ARRAY_AGG` function:

```
SELECT
  name,
  DATE(pubdate) AS pubdate,
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(url, statistic) ORDER BY statistic DESC LIMIT 2) AS top_urls
FROM dataset.table
GROUP BY name, pubdate
```

You can use a subquery with `UNNEST` to get rows as output without arrays:

```
SELECT name, pubdate, url, statistic
FROM (
  SELECT
    name,
    DATE(pubdate) AS pubdate,
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(url, statistic) ORDER BY statistic DESC LIMIT 2) AS top_urls
  FROM dataset.table
  GROUP BY name, pubdate
), UNNEST(top_urls)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    with xx as(
      select name, url, statistic, pubdate, row_number() over(partition by name , url order by statistic desc) rn 
      from topics)
select * except(rn) 
from xx 
where rn <= 2;
```